# Possibility to initialize Personal documents without logging in into portal

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, office365, onedrive

We create an Office 365 user programmatically via Powershell API, and then access corresponding Office 365 Sharepoint libraries using CSOM via .NET. We were able to do all that, except Personal documents library (OneDrive for Business) which doesn't appear unless user logs in into portal.microsoftonline.com. Is there a way to automatically initialize Personal documents without forcing user to use portal?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Request-SPOPersonalSite` cmdlet to pre-provision onedrives prior to a user login.

Details from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn792367.aspx

The Request-SPOPersonalSite cmdlet requests that the users specified be enqueued so that a Personal Site be created for each. The actual Personal site is created by a Timer Job later.